# Como resolver este erro de codificação (encoding error) no Pandas

Tags: python, codificação-de-caracteres, pandas

Estou tendo problema quando o python lê o xlsx com o pandas. Quando roda o `des_pt = (f_pt.head()[pt][0]).encode('utf-8').strip()` e coloca a variável pt. Tem um problema de encode pois alguns caracteres estão em utf-8.

```
import pandas as pd

create_result = open('resultado.json', 'w')
i = 0

file_name_pt = pd.ExcelFile('pt.xlsx', encoding='utf-8')
file_name_en = pd.ExcelFile('en.xlsx')

f_pt = pd.read_excel(file_name_pt, sheet_name='Sheet1')
title_pt = f_pt.columns[1:]

f_en = pd.read_excel(file_name_en, sheet_name='Sheet1')
title_en = f_en.columns[1:]

create_result.write('{\n"resultados": [\n')
while i <= 25:
    for pt,en in zip(title_pt, title_en):
        print pt
        pt = pt.encode('utf-8').strip()
        en = en.encode('utf-8').strip()
        print pt

        des_pt = (f_pt.head()[pt][0]).encode('utf-8').strip()
        des_en = (f_en.head()[en][0]).encode('utf-8').strip()

        print des_pt     
        create_result.write('{\n"id":%s,\n"nome":"%s",\n"name":"%s",\n"descricao":"%s",\n"description":"%s",\n"combinacoes":[]},\n'%(i, pt, en, '', des_en))
        i+=1
create_result.write(']\n}')
create_result.close()
print 'Done'
```

A mensagem de erro

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/atila/Desktop/PyAutomate/firjan_result_generator/firjangenerator.py", line 23, in <module>
>     des_pt = (f_pt.head()[pt][0]).encode('utf-8').strip()
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2688, in __getitem__
>     return self._getitem_column(key)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2695, in _getitem_column
>     return self._get_item_cache(key)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2486, in _get_item_cache
>     values = self._data.get(item)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4115, in get
>     loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3066, in get_loc
>     return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>   File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> KeyError: 'T\xc3\xa9cnico em Energias Renov\xc3\xa1veis'
> ```

Comment: Atila, considere escrever o texto em português, para ser respondido pela comunidade do SO em [inglês](https://stackoverflow.com) de uma olhada no fórum de lá diretamente. Procure não intitular o post com o log do erro , pois acrescenta pouco a descrição do seu problema.

Comment: Opa! Pode deixar. Não me atentei nesse detalhe

Comment: O problema é que voce modifica a chave e tenta acessar ela depois. Se comentar essa linha `pt = pt.encode('utf-8').strip()`, continua dando erro?

Comment: Nop! O código funciona de boas sem essa linha

Answer (score 0):

Você conseguiria disponibilizar o formato e algumas amostras do conteúdo (planilhas) que você está tentando ler?

Com a descrição da sua pergunta, a única coisa que consigo contribuir é o seguinte:

O erro `KeyError: 'T\xc3\xa9cnico em Energias Renov\xc3\xa1veis'` acontece pois ele está acessando uma estrutura de chave, valor (key, value) e ele não encontra a chave, no caso a string 'T\xc3\xa9cnico em Energias Renov\xc3\xa1veis'.

Pra poder te ajudar mais, talvez disponibilizar o conteúdo (pelo menos as primeiras linhas) dos arquivos que você está lendo.

Answer (score -1):

O problema está em`pt = pt.encode('utf-8').strip()`.

O KeyError é usado no pandas para quando você tenta acessar uma coluna com um nome que não está definido em seu data frame. Portanto, acredito que quando você faz o encode('utf-8'), você está capturando o nome errado da coluna.

Tente retirar o encode. Fica assim:`pt = pt.strip()`.

A linha de baixo também vai dar problema se tiver algum caracter estranho.
Para testar se esse de fato é o erro printe essa linha:`title_pt = f_pt.columns[1:]`, compare com essa linha:`pt = pt.encode('utf-8').strip()`